# How to collect value of dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-events

I am displaying a warning dialog box on `window close` event. If user clicks on <kbd>Cancel</kbd> control stays on same page or if user clicks on <kbd>Okay</kbd> he get navigated to desired page.
I want collect the value of dialog box means whether user have clicked on <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or <kbd>Okay</kbd>.I have written following code in external JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        window.onbeforeunload = askConfirm;
        
        function askConfirm()
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                // Message to be displayed in Warning.
                return "Your unsaved data will be lost.";
            }       
        } 
    }
```

How can I collect the value?

Comment: missing ); at the end of your code

Comment: Thanks Andriy :) I used `Ctrl+Shift+k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {

                return "Are you sure to close?";

            }

        </script>
```

example code

http://files.dropbox.com/u/642364/blogger/scripts/close.html

**EDIT**
Getting the response code from the user on window close

```
<body onUnload = "CheckIt ()" >
...
</body>
<script>
function CheckIt ()
{
  var response = confirm ("Are you closing..");
   alert (response); // do whatever for response.

}
</script>
```

Comment: I used the same code.Now I want get value of `Dialog Box`, I want to know whether user clicked on `Okay` or `Cancel`.

Comment: If you want to get the values (not cancelling the close request) could be done easily with onUnload event of the form. See the edited code

Comment: @Ajay: Thanks for the suggestion.I tried it but it anyways closes the window.What I want to do is if user clicks on `Okay` window should closed / navigated. When user clicks on `Cancel` some action should be done and control should remain on same page.

Comment: You need to `return` the boolean value held in `response`, which corresponds to the option they clicked on the confirm dialog; `Okay = true` and `Cancel = false`. You'll probably also want to call the code on the `onbeforeunload` event, rather than on the `onunload` event.

Comment: @Anthony: Could you please give more idea where and how to return `response` value ?

Comment: @Ajinkya I actually went and tested this myself quickly, and there are a couple of problems. First of all, most (probably all - I only tested FF4 and IE9) of the current browsers have their own dialogs that they display when there's an onbeforeunload event handler, and from the little research I've done there seems to be no way to prevent this. If you're happy with two dialogs, you can use your own confirm dialog, do some processing based on the result, return pretty much anything, then let the default browser dialog handle navigating away from/staying on the current page.

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for investing on this :) I am fine with different dialog box. So is there no way to collect value for `onBeforeUnload` dialog ?

Comment: @Ajinkya All of the examples I've found have simply been of the "display a warning if they have unsaved data" variety, unfortunately. Not much help with your particular problem, obviously.